# Failed to update data source credentials: The credentials provided for the OData source are invalid. Power BI Service & Microsoft Graph Explorer

Tags: powerbi, odata, credentials, microsoft-planner, graph-explorer

Currently I have an issue with Refreshing the dataset that I uploaded to the Power BI web service.

Please note that it works and able to refresh the data totally fine in Power BI Desktop.

The issue is in the data source connected to Odata Feed

[image]

I wanted to get all of my Microsoft Planner task data with this method and based on a few references requires me to use Microsoft Graph Explorer.

I am utilizing my organization account and have a Power BI pro license. The following error message is returned when attempting to refresh in Power BI service:

[image]

I attempted to re-establish the credentials but the same error persisted. Other sources such as SharePoint and dataflow do not exhibit any issues and refresh properly. The error only surfaces from the Odata Feed connection where I utilized Microsoft Graph Explorer to retrieve the task data in Microsoft Planner.

[image]

Any assistance would be highly appreciated, as I have spent the entire day trying to resolve this issue without any progress.

Comment: Try to visit this page, I open discussion at the microsoft forum.

https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Service/Failed-to-update-data-source-credentials-The-credentials/m-p/3319460#M200078

Comment: Yes Lack of Support for Microsoft Graph in Power Query https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connecting-to-graph 
You can use custom connectors or register an app in azure

Answer (score 1):

Checked the "Skip test Connection". Hope that will work.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check permissions on the data source, your app registration should at least have read access.

Then you need to check the API permissions on the app registration, you will need to add in the Power BI permissions.

Answer (score 0):

[Lack of Support for Microsoft Graph in Power Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connecting-to-graph)

there are many solution i found:

1- [use custom connector](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_qtPVc1Cyo) : but this solution need data gateway

2- [Register a new application](https://minkus.medium.com/easily-connecting-between-power-query-power-bi-and-microsoft-graph-72333eb95a35) I use this solution is perfect but if any one has access to power query will show the all information (secret key - tanant id - ....) to get any data without authorize